# I can ping Ubuntu VMs with large buffer size without enabling jumbo frame. Why is that?

Tags: ubuntu, jumbo-frames

I have a few VMs running on Hyper-V, some are running Windows Server 2012 R2 and some are running Ubuntu 16.04. On the Windows VMs, I have to enable jumbo frame to be able to ping them with large buffer size (`ping host.name -l 8972 -f`), otherwise it would result in timeout. However, I am able to ping the Ubuntu VMs with large buffer size without explicitly enabling jumbo frame on the Ubuntu VMs. What was the reason behind it?

Comment: The real question is why you need to enable jumbo frames to ping them with large buffer sizes. IP supports fragmentation and re-assembly. Why is it broken for the Windows 2012 VMs?

Comment: I'm using ping as a way to test if jumbo frame was configured properly, hence the -f.